# Why won't JAWS read this link on arrow navigation

Tags: accessibility, microsoft-edge, jaws-screen-reader

This markup is able to be read by JAWS arrow navigation in IE11, however in Microsoft Edge it only allows it to be fully read via tab navigation. Does anyone have any idea why Edge refuses to read this list item? We have other list items that are similar to this that are read just fine, but this one in particular doesn't seem to be available to be read via JAWS arrow navigation.

```
<li id="some-id">
    <a href="/destination"> 
    <span class="submenu"></span> 
    <span class="label">    Destination  </span>  
    <span class="count"> 
        <span class="value" data-info=0></span>
    </span>  
    </a>   
</li>
```

I've tried setting `data-info=0` with and without quotes. I'm stumped.

Comment: So tabbing to the `<a>` reads "Destination, link"?  What does using down arrow read?  Just "link"?  What does using "i" do?  ("L" will take you to the list.  "i" will take you to a list item.)

Comment: good question about "i" and "L" @slugolicious. I'll have to follow up on that.

The down arrow, just ends up skipping this list item and moves on to the next portion of our navigation. What's interesting is that it's only this list item and it doesn't seem to be limited to it's position in the nav. Makes me think we have invalid markup, but I'm not seeing it. 

We end up injecting text into the span with class value, but it's blank to start.

Comment: @slugolicious, "i" and "L" allow the list item to be read appropriately. However down arrow navigation doesn't seem to pick up this particular list item while managing to read the rest of the items in the list. It's quite strange. Mind you this seems to work fine for apple voiceover and chromevox. It's just JAWS with Edge specifically that's giving us a hard time ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: does edge have an 'accessibility tree viewer' option?  in firefox, i can bring up the code inspector and select the "accessibility" tab (new) and i can see the accessibility tree.  this will show you specifically whether an element is considered a list or a listitem and might help find the problem.